# Tkinter: Can you put a frame or grid inside a grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a periodic table program and I want to have a grid like setup with in a grid

[Here is an image of the effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSiNf.png)

Is this possible and if so how.
Thank you.

Comment: Look at `.grid`'s unofficial documentation [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111175154/http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm).

Comment: the short answer is: yes, You can put a frame inside a frame using grid. it is also pretty simple. just create a frame (or use the window as parent) then create say two more frames and set the parent as the first frame and grid those frame, then You can create more frames setting their parents as the two of the just mentioned frames and gridding them too and it will be like a frame inside a frame, inside a frame

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, just give the secondary frames the parent-frame as an argument, just like with any other widget in tkinter:

```
variable = tk.Widget(parent, widget, specifics)
```

in your case where you basicly want to display the same information for all elements I would create a subclass inhereting from `tk.Frame` class and passing all the relevant information to it, that way you only have to organize your small frames once.

You might want to start with something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.pack(fill="both", expand = True)
        
        
        # note how we're now not calling for the tk.Frame class anymore,
        # since we have our own custom one
        # when calling our class we can now pass information to it
        # right now only the name
        self.vanadium = ElementFrame(self.mainframe, "Vanadium")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.vanadium.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        self.chromium = ElementFrame(self.mainframe, "Chromium")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.chromium.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        
        self.niobium = ElementFrame(self.mainframe, "Niobium")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.niobium.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        
        self.molybdenum = ElementFrame(self.mainframe, "Molybdenum")
        #placing in the main frame
        self.molybdenum.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        
        
class ElementFrame(tk.Frame):
    
    # here we are defining what variables need to be passed for a successful call
    def __init__(self, parent, element):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        #pass variables through, like abbreviation, number, etc.
        self.element = element
        #organize your elements frame
        self.elementlabel = tk.Label(self, text = element)
        self.elementlabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        
        
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```